# I just tried this code in java and here is my output 011. Can anyone please explain me how this happend

Tags: java, loops

```
for(int i =0; i <= 1; i++) 
{
    for(int j =0; j <= i; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Output: `011`

I just want to know how this happened.

Comment: What do you not understand? What output were you expecting?

Comment: You're printing `i` in an inner loop. When `i` is `0`, `j` starts at `0`. `0 <= 0`. So the body is entered and `0` is printed. `j` is incremented and `1` is not `<=` `0`. So `i` is incremented, then `j` is `0` again...

Answer (score 3):

You have two loops:

```
for(int i =0; i <= 1; i++) //external loop
    for(int j =0; j <= i; j++) //internal loop
        System.out.print(i);
```

The **external loop** has 2 iteration since it starts in `i = 0` and ends in `i = 1` when `i` is incremented to `i = 2` you exit the for loop.

The **internal loop** has `i + 1` iterations.

When `i = 0` the internal loop iterates once. That`s when you get the **0**.

When `i = 1` the internal loop iterates twice (`j = 0` and `j = 1`). That`s when you get **11**

Comment: I am new to programming that's why I got stuck to nested for loops and uploaded this short piece of code to understand in better way. Thanks Pshemo and jpuriol